# Why is there such a problem as 'GET <audio> error'?

Tags: javascript, audio, mobile-safari

In the beginning I would create a persistent audio object. like:

```
const audio = new Audio()
audio.src = "xxx.mp3"
document.body.appendChild(audio)
```

In running, I'll invoke `audio.play()` multiple times.
In general, it works OK.
But in the ios safari browser,It occasionally goes wrong.
Error message showing `GET <audio> error`. like:

[GET <audio> error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDswh.png)

So I wonder how this error came about.

Answer (score 0):

GET is an internet protocol method. It fails for some reason, and the browser shows it. I would suggest try to listen for that error and replay if possible (i.e call play again) if GET error present.